# Bluetooth device is not getting disconnected

Tags: android, xamarin.android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing Xamarin android native application where to connect the Bluetooth devices using Plugin.BLE 1.3.0 library. Actually, our application should have the following features that connect multiple Bluetooth devices one by one and disconnect those devices one by one.

The beauty is, we are able to connect the device one by one as expected, but we are getting issues while disconnecting this device. Actually, I have 5 Bluetooth devices where I have tried to connect one by one then disconnecting the device one by one.

Most of times it was successful , but few times the Bluetooth device is not getting disconnected and LED light not turns off.

Whenever the disconnection issue happens, I have checked the Bluethooth Adapter instance, but the Bluethooth adapter has not maintain the connected device information which we have disconnected now. Somehow the Bluetooth manager (adapter) lost the device information and remain the connected state only until restart the mobile then the device connection is getting disconnected.

To connect the device, I am calling the below code:

```
bool UseAutoConnect = false;
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
await    CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(device, new
```

ConnectParameters(autoConnect: UseAutoConnect, forceBleTransport:false),  tokenSource.Token);

To disconnect the device, I am calling the below code:

```
await CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter.DisconnectDeviceAsync(device);
```

Could you please suggest that how to handle the disconnect device one by one when we have multiple connected?

Configuration:-

```
Version of the Plugin: Plugin.BLE
version="1.3.0" targetFramework="portable46-net451+win81"
https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le

Platform:: Android API 21

Device: Samsung Tab S3, Google Pixel XL, Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime (Android 7.0)
```

Comment: Does all the device have this issue?

Comment: So far I have tested with 6 devices. Most of the time, It happened to 2 devices , sometimes 1 device..